# UiPath selectors not working in Microsoft Remote Desktop app

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, uipath, uipath-robot

I'm trying to build a robot which is run on my local system but acts upon the Remote Desktop through UiPath's Native RDP support. I've installed the Microsoft Remote Desktop Apps extension on my local system, and the Remote Runtime in my desitnation remote machine.

When I had used the Remote Desktop Connection application to connect to the remote and machine and work with Uipath, every selector worked with just minor modifications.

Now I've had to switch over to use Microsoft Remote Desktop app to connect to Remote machine and use the same. However, Uipath is not able to recognize any sort of selector inside the remote machine now.
What could be the reason for this? It works perfectly fine with Windows' built in Remote Desktop Connection, but not with Microsoft Remote Desktop. Any solution can be worked around for this?